# Is there a standard way to send data with light pulses?

Tags: networking, arduino

I'm looking at writing something for Arduino (having played extensively with Pi). One of the things I'd like to do is be able to set up the Arduino's wifi using a desktop computer.

What I was thinking to do was let the user write their wifi settings into the browser, which would then convert this to a series of light pulses that the arduino could decode, just by holding is near the screen. (i.e. robot morse code)

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: I have no experience with Arduino so I don't know if this viable, but have you considered using QR codes?

Comment: I was looking for something a little more 'low-tech' - QR codes are good if you have a camera but I want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about using some IR protocol to get this done (you just need to change frequency since it may be a bit harder to control). The most used one is the NEC IR Protocol, really easy to understand and to implement: http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/NEC+Infrared+Transmission+Protocol

I think you can tweak that to achieve your goal.

---

Now, some workarounds, it's not a straight answer to your question, but like you are asking for a standard way to do it, there may be a different way (even simpler) than light pulses.

Do you know TI SmartConfig ?

Basicaly, the wifi chip is listening in promiscuous mode and is waiting some special UDP packets containing SSID informations and configuration (this paquet can be sent from a mobile device like an iPhone).

You can make your own implementation of it or use same standard as TI in order to be able to use their mobile configuration apps.

---

Another solution is to look to all wifi SSID around, and once it finds one with some special formatting, it uses this special formatting to configure itself.

For exemple you want the arduino to connect to SSID: `my_wifi` and Passphrase: `abcdefgh1234`
So just configure an adhoc wifi on one of your device (even from a smartphone) with this as SSID (or any format you want even some crypted one if you are worried about security): `Ard--my_wifi---abcdefgh1234`
Configure your arduino to check for SSID starting with `Ard--`, it will find this one, and get the wanted wifi configuration. Once it's done, association is complete and the adhoc wifi is no longer needed.

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3000_Smart_Config